# developing to maclaurin Series $f(x)=\frac{2x+3}{x^2 -4x+5}$ on $x=2$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

> $$f(x)=\frac{2x+3}{x^2 -4x+5}$$ on $x=2$.

My solution:

$t=x-2 $ => $x=t+2$ , we get:
$f(t)=\frac{2t+7}{t^2+1}$  on $t=0$.

then: $(2t+7)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty } {(-t^2)^n} =
(2t+7)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }{(-1)^nt^{2n}}$.

The solution **MUST BE** of the form: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g(n)(x-2)^{h(n)}$.

Any help on how to continue?

Thanks.

Comment: is $f$ differentiable at $x=2$ ? what are the successive derivatives ?

Comment: I dont know what differentiable and successive derivatives means. If you want I can show the answer from my book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach looks good. In what form do you want/need it?

You could rewrite:
$$(2t+7) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nt^{2n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(2t+7)t^{2n}  = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\left( 2t^{2n+1}+7t^{2n} \right)$$
And substitute back to $x$:
$$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\left( 2(x-2)^{2n+1}+7(x-2)^{2n} \right)$$

---

If you really want it in the standard form
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x-2)^n$$
then you can group the powers of $(x-2)$ but you'll need some adjustments to get the coefficients of the even and odd powers right. The odd powers have coefficient $2$ and $(1-(-1)^n)/2$ is $1$ for $n$ odd and $0$ for $n$ even; so the contribution of the odd terms can be put into the factor:
$$\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}2$$
In a similar way, the contribution of the even terms can be put into the factor:
$$\frac{1-(-1)^{n+1}}{2}7$$
That would give the following factor which can be simplified:
$$\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}2+\frac{1-(-1)^{n+1}}{2}7
= \tfrac{1}{2} \left( 9+5 (-1)^n \right)  $$
Note however that we still didn't take the factor $(-1)^n$ into account; this now has to alternate every two terms (1, 1, -1, -1, ...). You can do this with sines and cosines or e.g. with a factor:
$$(-1)^{\tfrac{1}{4}\left( 2n-1+(-1)^n \right)}$$
to give:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{\tfrac{1}{4}\left( 2n-1+(-1)^n \right)}\tfrac{1}{2} \left( 9+5 (-1)^n \right) (x-2)^n$$

Comment: Both forms are not acceptable. It needs to be : $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g(n)(x-2)^{h(n)}$

Comment: Why do you want in that form? The MacLaurin Series is as it is (see above) and doesn't necessarily have an *easy* of *elegant* closed form. Are you required to write it in this form?

Comment: Yes I'm required to write that in this praticular form. I have the solution if you want to see first. Thank you anyway for your efford.

Comment: That might be handy to point you in the right direction (for me or others); I would include it in your initial question.

Comment: Not sure if this is the easiest form! But continuing on your (and mine) earlier efforts, I've added a piece to get it into standard form.